# How to show all site collections using web part in my Home page

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, site, web, collection

Is there a way that I could show all my site collection within my web application?
Something like this:
[image]

Comment: is it online or on prem?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthVaghasia! it's on premise

Answer (score 1):

You could use content query web part to achieve that. Have a look at this question and the links to see more examples.

[show site collections where the user has access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79904/show-site-collections-where-the-user-has-access)